# Problems when using a HTML5 web site off line with jQuery and Fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, offline

I've built a web site using jQuery and Fancybox. It works fine on the web but I'd like to put it on a Hoo-Too Tripmate Titan to access it offline. The thing is it doesn't work although jQuery and Fancybox are included in the web site tree.

Here's the code of the the calls to the libraries.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/general.css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/icone_site.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/icone_site.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="images/icone_site.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/icone_site.png" />
<script src="jquery/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>



<!-- Add fancyBox -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>

<!-- Optionally add helpers - button, thumbnail and/or media -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.6"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7"></script>
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Are you sure your relative paths are working? view the source code from your browser and click on the links to the libraries

Comment: Hello ! All the files are there, as the web site is already online : I downloaded all the files from the web server. I've just checked all the links to these files. They all are in the right directories !

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? Have you checked console for any clue?